# Как мне из python(django) вывести переменную в javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Мне нужно views.py:

```js
class IndexView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tit = ['Год', 'Россия', 'США']
        context = {
            'tit': tit
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Мой код html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>{{ tit }}</p>

<script>
var tit = {{ tit }};
console.log(tit);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Выдает ошибку в консоли:

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'
```

Что это может значить?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
var tit = {{ tit }};
console.log(tit);
</script>
```

Выведет

```
<script>html
var tit = [Год, Россия, США];
console.log(tit);
</script>
```

Проверяйте, что получаете в шаблоне.

Тут либо в ручную рендерить, циклами, либо использовать [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)